# c# templates how can i apply constraints to a class that derives from something

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

stoopid question time again.

I have this class that pulls in some code via a base class like so:

```
class TVIRoot : OURTreeNodeImpl { }
```

I now want to add some template functionality

```
class TVIRoot<TLabelHandler> : OURTreeNodeImpl { }
```

But I can't work out what sort of finger mangling I need to get it to compile when I need to supply some constraints.

```
class TVIRoot<TLabelHandler> where TLabelHandler : new(), OURTreeNodeImpl { } //no    
class TVIRoot<TLabelHandler> where TLabelHandler : SomeClass : OURTreeNodeImpl { } //no
class TVIRoot<TLabelHandler> : OURTreeNodeImpl, where TLabelHandler : SomeClass { } //no
```

Can this be done?

Many thanks.

bg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TVIRoot<TLabelHandler> : OURTreeNodeImpl where TLabelHandler : SomeClass { } //yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraint comes after the base class inheritance, here is an example:

```
public interface  IFood
{
}

public class Animal
{
}

public class Cat<T> : Animal where T : IFood
{
    public void Eat(T food)
    {
    }
}
```

for more details check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx